# How to go about linking AWS SDK CPP built from source into a Qt/QML app subdir project?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, qt, amazon-s3, qml

First up my knowledge of c/c++ is limited to compilation where the practical included writing a compiler for educational purposes.
Now my job involved creating AWS S3 bucket manually and putting some files in it and accessing from a Qt application(basically c++ code).

What I have done till now is built AWS SDK CPP with steps mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup-windows.html).

Then to create a directory of .h files ripped apart the source code retaining only the .h files by power shell script:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\qt-aws\xxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxx" -Filter *.* -Exclude *.h -Recurse 
foreach ($file in $folders)
{
if(Test-Path $file  -Exclude *.h -PathType leaf)
{
echo "deleting $file"
del $file
}
else
{

}
}

Write-Host "Congratulations! Your first script executed successfully"
```

My AWSS3Access Qt project pro file contains

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
AWS_DIR = "C:/Program Files/AWS"
AWS_SDK_DIR = "C:/Program Files/AWS/AWS_BUILD"
INCLUDEPATH *= $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-s3/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/verification/cbmc/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-io/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-mqtt/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-auth/include \
                $${AWS_DIR}/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-sdkutils/include

LIBS *= -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-cpp-sdk-s3 \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-cpp-sdk-core \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-crt-cpp \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-auth \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-cal \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-common \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-compression \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-event-stream \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-checksums \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-http \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-io \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-mqtt \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-s3 \
        -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR} -laws-c-sdkutils

SOURCES += \
        AwsS3Master.cpp \
        main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    AwsS3Master.hpp
```

AWSS3Master.hpp

```
#ifndef AWSS3MASTER_HPP
#define AWSS3MASTER_HPP
#define USE_IMPORT_EXPORT
#include <iostream>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/Object.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
class AwsS3Master
{
public:
    AwsS3Master();
    void listObjects();
    void setBucket(const Aws::String& bucketName);
    void setRegion(const Aws::String& region);
private:
    Aws::String _region{"region"};
    Aws::String _bucket{"bucket"};
    Aws::String accessKey{"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"};
    Aws::String accessSecret{"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"};
};

#endif // AWSS3MASTER_HPP
```

and the cpp file AWSS3Master.cpp file has a function named list objects

```
void AwsS3Master::listObjects()
{

    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    {
        Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
        if (!_region.empty())
        {
            clientConfig.region = _region;
        }
        Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
        credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId(Aws::String(accessKey));
        credentials.SetAWSSecretKey(Aws::String(accessSecret));
        Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(credentials, clientConfig);
     //   s3_client.
        Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsRequest objects_request;

        objects_request.WithBucket(_bucket);//.WithPrefix("some-prefox");

        bool isDone = false;
        bool isFailed= false;
        Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsOutcome outcome;
        int c=0;

        while(!isDone) {
            outcome=s3_client.ListObjects(objects_request);
            if(!outcome.IsSuccess()) break;
            //process
            Aws::Vector<Aws::S3::Model::Object> object_list = outcome.GetResult().GetContents();

            for (auto const &s3_object : object_list)
            {
                std::cout << "* " << s3_object.GetKey() << std::endl;
                c++;

            }
            std::cout<<"--------- Break"<<c<<"\n";
            isDone=!outcome.GetResult().GetIsTruncated();
            if(!isDone) {
                //objects_request.SetMarker(outcome.GetResult().GetNextMarker());
                objects_request.SetMarker(outcome.GetResult().GetContents().back().GetKey());
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Count "<<c<<"\n";
        //check isFailed
        if(!outcome.IsSuccess()) {
            std::cout << "ListObjects error: " <<
                         outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << " " <<
                         outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
}
```

the main.cpp has

```
#include <iostream>
#include <AwsS3Master.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    AwsS3Master awss3;
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    //TODO: Change bucket_name to the name of a bucket in your account.
    const Aws::String bucket_name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    //TODO: Set to the AWS Region in which the bucket was created.
    const Aws::String region = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    std::cout << "Beginning of file contents:\n";
    awss3.setBucket(bucket_name);
    awss3.setRegion(region);
    awss3.listObjects();
return 0;
}
```

While all this is listing the files in the bucket..
**I want to include this project as a sub project of another project** that uses it to access s3 buckets.
I am trying to wrap my head around things like statically linked and dynamically linked libraries etc

I have used .h files from source, .lib and .dll files generated by command

```
cmake ..\aws\aws-sdk-cpp -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_ONLY="s3"
```

Is this approach right? Is there any other easier way I can include the AWS-SDK-CPP into my Qt application? esp creating the pri/pro file should be easier than what I have done.
I know MSBuild step creates the library files in
C:\Program Files (x86)\aws-cpp-sdk-all\bin
which along with lib and include folders that could have been used.

Comment: This is mid-2022. Do not use qmake. Use cmake instead.

Comment: I image your powershell script could be replaced with `cmake install`

Comment: @AlanBirtles This last step `msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj -p:Configuration=[Debug | Release]` puts all built files in programFiles(x86) folder called aws-cpp-sdk-all.. So how should I change the configuration to release when I need to package the app.. Debug libraries won't work with release mode right

Comment: so in my pro file I could use 
Debug: AWS_SDK_DIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\aws-cpp-sdk-all\Debug\...path to lib
Release: AWS_SDK_DIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\aws-cpp-sdk-all\Release\...path to lib
is this the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after so many missteps I found out that in .pro/.pri file you could switch between debug and release like

```
Debug: AWS_SDK_DIR = "C:/Program Files/AWS/Debug/AWS_BUILD"
Release: AWS_SDK_DIR = "C:/Program Files/AWS/Release/AWS_BUILD"
```

which is where you put your lib files..
and dll files in

```
Debug: AWS_SDK_DIR_BIN = "C:/Program Files/AWS/Debug/bin"
Release: AWS_SDK_DIR_BIN = "C:/Program Files/AWS/Release/bin"
```

Finally just include the respective bin folder with dlls

like this

```
LIBS += -L$${AWS_SDK_DIR_BIN}
```

And your project compiles/builds/runs without problem in both debug and release modes.